# Negation of "...then $n$ has at least one prime factor $p$ with $1 \lt p \le \sqrt{n}$" for a proof by contradiction.

Tags: proof-writing

This is what I'm trying to proof:

*If $n$ is a positive composite number, then $n$ has at least one prime factor $p$ with $1 \lt p \le \sqrt{n}$*

But I'm a bit confused about how to properly negate the conclusion so I can use contradiction.
First, I realized (correct me if I'm wrong) that the conclusion can be rewritten in the form *there exists...* so it would read:

*...there exists a prime factor p, such that $1 \lt p \le \sqrt{n}$*

Then, according to Sollow's book, the negation would be something like:

*for every prime factor $p$, $p\le1$ or $p\gt\sqrt{n}$*

But then I wondered if, instead, it could be written like this:

*for every prime number $p$, $p$ is not a factor of n, or $p\le1$ or $p\gt\sqrt{n}$*

For wich I would see, first, what happens if I say $p$ is not  a factor, and then use *$p\le1$ or $p\gt\sqrt{n}$* in some manner.

I incline for the former, but then again, it's a bit confusing, and since I'm still learning how to do proofs (I'm self-taught) then I think this particular form of proposition can bring some valuable information for future proofs. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since there are no primes $≤1$ you don't need to  carry that part of the contrapositive expression around.  It's enough to say that the contrapositive is "there exists a composite positive number $n$ for which all the prime factors are $>\sqrt n$".

Comment: *prime* is redundant here, as you can say "If $n$ is a positive composite number, then $n$ has at least one factor (divisor, if you prefer) $p$ with $1<p \le \sqrt{n}$."  The negation of the second part could then be: "Every factor (divisor) of $n$ is $1$ or strictly greater than $ \sqrt{n}$"

Comment: Both of your negations are correct and equivalent. When proving **A or B**, you can assume **not A**, and then prove **B** (in other words, **A or B** is the same as **not A $\Rightarrow$ B**). So in your context "$p$ is not a factor of $n$ or blah" is equivalent to "if $p$ is a factor of $n$, then blah".

Comment: @Henry You are certainly correct. Thanks!

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the observation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more common negation would be "..., then **no** prime factor of $n$ lies between $1$ and $\sqrt{n}$."

And then, since all prime factors are positive, you could rewrite that as "then all prime factors of $n$ are greater than $\sqrt{n}$. "

And that's a form where it's particularly easy to reach the conclusion you want (i.e., contradiction). For if $n$ is composite, then it has at least two prime factors (possible equal).

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

If the theorem you are trying to prove is stated as

> **If** $n$ is a positive composite integer, **then** it has at least one prime factor $p$ satisfying $1\lt p\le \sqrt{n}$.

we can rephrase it as

> $\forall n\in\mathbb Z^+, n \text{ composite}, \exists p \text{ a prime factor of } n \text{ such that } 1\lt p\le \sqrt{n}.$

and the negation is

> $\exists n\in\mathbb Z^+, n \text{ composite}, \nexists p \text{ a prime factor of } n \text{ such that } 1\lt p\le \sqrt{n}.$

or

> There exists a positive composite integer $n$ with no prime factor $p$ satisfying $1\lt p\le \sqrt{n}$.

If you want to use a proof by contradiction, assume that this statement is true and consider a positive composite integer $n$ with no prime factors $p$ satisfying $1\lt p \le \sqrt{n}$, and try to derive a contradiction from that. If this gives you a contradiction, you may reject the negation of the original statement and conclude that the original statement is true.

Comment: Thank you very much, actually rephrasing the proposition using the symbols makes it quite easier!

Comment: @Dr.Pulque Great! If it was helpful, don’t forget to $\uparrow$ and $\checkmark$!